# Variable is undefined after it leaves scope of getJSON function, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, undefined

Here is my code:

```
var my_json;
$.getJSON("file.json", function(json) {
  my_json = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
  my_json = JSON.parse(my_json);
  console.log('in', my_json); // prints json
});
console.log('after', my_json); // prints undefined
```

I'm trying to load that JSON file, but for some reason the variable my_json becomes undefined the moment it leaves the scope of the getJSON function. When I print my_json in the getJSON, it looks fine and has the JSON info.
The console prints this out:
`in (json object)` and `after undefined`. I am pretty confused about this. The functions fetch and require haven't worked for me either, which is why I'm using this. When I try to use them, I get this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: "the moment it leaves the scope of the getJSON function" — No. You're logging it **before**.

Comment: Would you have any idea how to add a callback onto this? I'm trying to understand them but I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: The function starting `function(json)` **is** a callback.

Comment: So... I don't really understand. I've been reading up in the last hour or so but I still have no idea how I would get the data into my_json. Any clues for me?

Comment: `console.log('in', my_json); // prints json` — it is in `my_json` you are using it successfully there, continue to use it successfully **there** to do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I managed to figure it out.